# Access Security Area Azure DevOps Server on-premise via REST

Tags: azure-devops

I want to get all PATs via REST from Azure DevOps Server (on-premise). The REST API Docs show only access to Azure DevOps Services (hosted) with this URI

[https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/tokenadmin/personalaccesstokens/{subjectDescriptor}?api-version=7.1-preview.1](https://vssps.dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/tokenadmin/personalaccesstokens/%7BsubjectDescriptor%7D?api-version=7.1-preview.1)

How do I access the security areas (Identities, Accounts, etc.) via REST in Azure DevOps Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could visit the page below for the token administration rest api.

[Token Administration REST API for Azure DevOps Services - Azure DevOps Services REST API | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokenadmin/?view=azure-devops-server-rest-6.0)

And you can check the api for the different workspaces with the dropdown list below.
[image]

1.List Personal Access Tokens

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/_apis/tokenadmin/personalaccesstokens/{subjectDescriptor}?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

2.Read identities

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/_apis/identities?api-version=6.0
```

3.For security

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/?view=azure-devops-server-rest-6.0